# All flutter web apps are broken

Tags: flutter, web

Several projects we've written in Flutter are broken this morning due to failing to download https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.35.0/bin/canvaskit.js.  Production sites aren't getting paste their splash screens.

Answer (score 0):

We got our sites going again by deploying them again passing argument to tell it to get the cansvaskit locally:
`flutter build web --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=OURBASEURL/canvaskit/`

Answer (score 0):

It also appears as though the original issue is resolved at unpkg.com.

Answer (score 0):

A little earlier [unpkg was down](https://github.com/mjackson/unpkg/issues/343).  It looks like it is back up now, but with a CORS policy that is not allowing it to be downloaded from other sites (other sites running Flutter).

I was able to resolve by switching to the HTML renderer in `web/index.html`:

```html
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
    //window.flutterWebRenderer = "canvaskit";
  </script>
```

You can also specify the canvaskit url: pass `--dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=...` and host your own copy of CanvasKit at the URL specified in the `--dart-define`.

To use the jsdelivr CDN, use the command:

```
flutter build web --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvaskit-wasm@0.35.0/bin/canvaskit.wasm
```